# Chrome Developer Tools shows favicon 404 error in Brackets LivePreview

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, adobe-brackets

I've just started doing Anthony Alicea's "[Javascript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.udemy.com/understand-javascript)" course, and he's using the live preview feature of Brackets to demo his code. The first module is a barebones HTML page with a script tag linking to an empty JS file. When I open this page in Brackets and run the live preview, Dev Tools complains the favicon file is missing.

[image: Favicon error in Chrome Developer Tools]

I know it's a minor error, but it's annoying: I'd like a clean console when I'm working through the code examples for the course. I'm not sure if it's Brackets or Dev Tools that's doing this. Is there any way I can silence the error that doesn't involve adding a dummy favicon to every section's code folder?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To solve this error just add this reference in :

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />
```

Comment: Great work around. For those wondering, this is a base64 encoded image. Read more on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: Er... sorry, but "add this reference" where?

Comment: What's the data though? A broken image?

Comment: You might get the console error `net::ERR_INVALID_URL` with this answer. In order to remove that error, remove the ; character from the URL. So it would be like this:

`<link rel="icon" href="data:base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />`

Answer (score 7):

This is basically how browsers work, they try to look for a favicon.ico in the root folder if none is specified in the meta tags.

There is a simple solution to filter it out though, but it will remove any network related errors from the console (but you can of course still see it in the Network-tab). Click the filter icon (the one that looks like a funnel next to `<top frame>` in the console window and then check "Hide network messages" and you should be fine.

Comment: OK thanks - this is a pretty annoying behaviour - I'd expect the browser just to show its default favicon if it finds none. In case useful to anybody, this answer elsewhere on StackExchange suggests adding a base64 encoded blank favicon: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34544/can-i-instruct-the-browser-not-to-look-for-a-favicon.

Comment: It's mostly a legacy thing. In the dark ages of the internet (Internet Explorer 5) someone thought it a good idea to put a favicon at `/favicon.ico` and then it kinda stuck. It's so widely used today (since it's easy and beginners like easy stuff) that it would "break" a lot of sites if the browsers removed it so it'll probably be around forever.

Comment: Thanks for the background!

Answer (score 1):

Just add any `favicon.ico` file in root folder. Just like in image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can save the** `favicon.ico` **file and specify its location:**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

**or you can add a picture in text format (e.g. `Base64`):**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAdUlEQVR4AY3BsQmFQBBAwbeLiaFNmIt2cj3YhYVYhK2IuT2YGsn6WWS5Cw7+jNgPf1AqpolCw0eEkBIcB4jAusI8g5IRwW0bPA9cF0HJmFHoOoJS0bYUlIr7pqBkhgE3jrjzJCiZfcctC67vCQ0fM0JKYEbhBV2WHBhF7w0KAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
```

**or from some external service:**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"  type="image/x-icon" href="https:example.com/favicon.ico />
```